# How to write a pickup measure with 5/16 duration in Lilypond?

Tags: time-signatures, lilypond, meter, anacrusis

I'm trying to write sheet music for a piece with a pickup measure of 5 sixteenth notes. Lilypond has the [`\partial`](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/learning/advanced-rhythmic-commands) command for this, but it only accepts a single duration. That duration may be dotted, but that doesn't help since I need 5 notes, not 3, 6 or 7.

I've tried various combinations of partials, e.g. using the command twice:

```
\version "2.16.0"

\relative c'' {
    \key g \major
    \partial 4 \partial 16 g16 g fis d b | e2
}
```

which produces a barcheck warning

> ```
> warning: barcheck failed at: 1/4
>    \partial 4 \partial 16 g16 g fis d b 
>                                         | e2
> ```

and a wrong result:

[image]

I've tried other things like `\partial { 4 16 }` or `\partial 4~16` but nothing seems to work; either the pickup measure is ignored or it has a wrong length.

Is there any solution for this? I don't want to use a pickup measure of one half note with 3 sixteenth rests.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`\partial 16*5`.  Some people prefer writing `\partial 1*5/16` which scales `\partial 1` by the fraction `5/16`, but I'd lean towards the simpler version.

[image]

Comment: Clever! I've seen that `*` for multi-measure rests, but never for notes or things like this. I even't can't find a definition for this notation in the documentation. Or is it a general Scheme trick?

Comment: @Glorfindel It's documented [here](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/writing-rhythms#scaling-durations). `\partial` isn't mentioned, but it works anywhere a note-like duration is expected. It has nothing to do with Scheme, although you can use a Scheme expression as the scaling factor as mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I've found one workaround, but I'm not sure I really like it since the sum of the `\partial` durations is longer than the actual pickup measure:

```
\version "2.16.0"

\relative c'' {
    \key g \major
    \partial 4 g16 \partial 4 g fis d b | e2
}
```

and Lilypond warns about this:

> ```
> trying to use \partial after the start of a piece
>    \partial 4 g16 
>                   \partial 4 g fis d b | e2
> ```

but the result is correct:

[image]

Using `\partial 4 g16 g fis d \partial 16 b | e2` instead doesn't work properly, since it inserts a bar line after the `d` already (and produces a warning in the compiler):

[image]

I'm really interested in a better solution (if it exists)!

Answer (score -3):

Try: `\partial 16 * 5 g16 g16 fes16 d16 b16 |  e2`

Comment: Is this any different to user72605's answer?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace yes - it replaces the `fis` in my question with a different, wrong note. For someone who has severe problems reading staffs with more than two flats, that even borders on an insult ...